# How to scale down the effect

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have just download minimal titles effect from free website and i want to adjust the effect in my custom page.

When i scale down or transform it the effect get disturb.

How can i scale down and get the effect which is default. Is there any group to scale down all.

**Original effect**

[image]

**When i try to scale down**

[image]

How to scale down and adjust all the layer with the effect and text. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_yspIvkCrQnw_c3bjBnlXjQAjQDqGC8x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're scaling down each object independently, so they scale based on their respective anchor points, which obviously isn't what you want...

The whole thing will be in its own composition, so ideally what you do is place that composition in whatever other composition you want to use it in, and scale that as a whole. If the layers aren't in their own composition and are already part of a larger composition you can select all the layers in the timeline, right click and select "Pre-Compose...", which will create a new composition containing just those layers, which you can then scale.

Another option, if you want to keep them in the same composition is to create a null object, parent all the layers you want to scale to that null object and scale the null object.

[image]

[image]

---

ETA: I had a look at your file...

All the layers you need to transform are already parented to a null object ("Null 28"), but that layer already has scale values keyframed. You can either adjust the values of the two existing keyframes (you can either double click a keyframe to change the value via an input, or move the current-time indicator to that keyframe and change the value on the fly), making sure you don't add any *new* keyframes (or it'll mess up the effect). Or....

Create a new null object, parent "Null 28" to the new null object and scale the new null object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Im new to after effect and in my timeline i can see 2 layers (control and Text A) And the above screenshot you have 6-7 layers where they came from are they hidden or? plz explain.

Comment: @mehjam2018 they are hidden, if you look at the row of icons next to the search bar above the layers, the third one (looks like a face hiding) will show/hide them